# Как получить случайные элементы массива без повторений? (JS)

Tags: javascript

Есть массив со списком городов. Нужно брать случайные 10 элементов данного массива, но повторений быть не должно. 
Подскажите, как правильно реализовать? Сейчас выводятся с повторениями.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
let list = document.querySelector('#list');

let cities = ["Москва", "Санкт-Петербург", "Новосибирск", "Екатеринбург", "Нижний Новгород", "Казань", "Челябинск", "Омск", "Самара", "Ростов-на-Дону", "Уфа", "Красноярск", "Пермь", "Воронеж", "Волгоград", "Краснодар"];

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  for ( let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    let citi = cities[Math.floor(Math.random() * (16 - 0)) + 0];
    let item = document.createElement('li');
    list.append(item);
    item.textContent = citi;
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">Получить список городов</button>
<ol id="list"></ol>
```

Comment: так, еще раз: перемешиваете случайно массив и берете первые N элементов. Все)

Comment: @ThisMan это верный подход, однако если список очень большой, лучше выбирать не повоторяющиеся индексы

Answer (score 2):

Ваша задача сводится к тому чтобы взять случайный элемент среди всего множества, затем случайный среди оставшихся, за исключением первого взятого, затем случайный за исключением первых двух и так далее.

Самый простой вариант: выбираете случайный элемент, меняете его местами с первым, затем выбираете случайный кроме первого, меняете местами со вторым и так далее

```
  for (var i = 0 ; (i < 10) && (i < cities.length) ; i++) {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cities.length - i)) + i;
    var city = cities[r];
    cities[r] = cities[i];
    cities[i] = city;

    let item = document.createElement('li');
    list.append(item);
    item.textContent = city;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
let list = document.querySelector('#list');

let cities = ["Москва", "Санкт-Петербург", "Новосибирск", "Екатеринбург", "Нижний Новгород", "Казань", "Челябинск", "Омск", "Самара", "Ростов-на-Дону", "Уфа", "Красноярск", "Пермь", "Воронеж", "Волгоград", "Краснодар"];

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let c = cities.map(item => item);
  for ( let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    let ind = Math.floor(Math.random() * c.length);
    let item = document.createElement('li');
    list.append(item);
    item.textContent = c[ind];
    c.splice(ind, 1);
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">Получить список городов</button>
<ol id="list"></ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let cities = [
    "Москва", 
    "Санкт-Петербург", 
    "Новосибирск",
    "Екатеринбург",
    "Нижний Новгород", 
    "Казань", 
    "Челябинск", 
    "Омск", 
    "Самара", 
    "Ростов-на-Дону", 
    "Уфа", 
    "Красноярск", 
    "Пермь", 
    "Воронеж",
    "Волгоград",
    "Краснодар",
    "Москва", 
    "Санкт-Петербург", 
    "Новосибирск",
    "Екатеринбург",
    "Нижний Новгород", 
    "Казань", 
    "Челябинск", 
    "Омск", 
    "Самара", 
    "Ростов-на-Дону", 
    "Уфа", 
    "Красноярск", 
    "Пермь", 
    "Воронеж",
    "Волгоград",
    "Краснодар"
    ];

  let result = [];

  getRandomInt = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));


  while (result.length != 10) {
    let index = getRandomInt(cities.length);    
    result.push(cities[index]);    
    result = result.filter((v, i, arr) =>  arr.indexOf(v) == i);
  }
```